# How to combine all the elements of a member list with another property using Lambda in one list?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

I know this can be solved using a for-loop and a model class but I am curious how would you do this using only lambda expressions with a resulting anonymous object.

Say I have a class

```
public class GameReport
{
    public GameReport()
    {
        Entries = new List<ReportEntry>();
    }

    public string GameName { get; set; }
    public List<ReportEntry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

and using this class I instantiated an object

```
List<GameReport> gameReports = new List<GameReport>();
```

I then populate this list with the necessary values (including the Entries list), now I need to use a Lambda expression to create a new list composed of anonymous objects that contains something like

```
new { GameName, SingleEntry}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = (from g in gameReports
             from e in g.Entries
             select new { g.GameName, Entry = e }).ToList();
```

Or using `SelectMany` method with method-based query:

```
var items = gameReports.SelectMany(g => g.Entries
                                        .Select(e => new
                                                     { 
                                                         g.GameName,
                                                         Entry = e
                                                     })).ToList();
```

The first one will be transformed into the second one by compiler on compilation.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be this simple!